# USB ports working only with selected devices

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, keyboard, motherboard

Desktop with Asus motherboard H81m-a/br , an Intel I5, and Win10 64 bits installed.

There are 8 USD ports available :
Front: 2x 2.0
Back: 2x 3.0(blue) and 4x 2.0 (black).

All devices (wifi , keyboard) work with front ports.

The problem is the back ports. They are not working for keyboard. I have plug it in any of the back ports but Win10 still does not install it. If I plug it in the front port, it works ok (work ok in another computer too) .  BUT, there is an USB mouse receiver using on of these back USB ports, working ok. I change this receiver to another USB back port, still works, and then use this previous port to plug the keyboard (where mouse receiver was working), but the keyboard does not work (even lights does not turn on).

It`s a newly install of win10, from zero, on a new SSD, did few days ago. Windows Update show it`s all updated. Device Mgmt shows an USB on "yellow alert" icon (enumeration error 43), but "update driver" and "remove and install" it again does not work, remains with yellow error.

Edit: there is also a printer USB using one back port, and working.
Edit2: Just plug iPhone with USB there and it works.

What could be happen ? How to solve ?

Comment: Have you tried any other keyboard, just to be sure the problem is somewhere else?

Comment: This keyboard would replace the current PS2 installed and working. I don`t have another USB keyboard right now to test. I will test with other USB devices.

Comment: What is the model of this keyboard that has the yellow alert icon on its receiver?

Comment: Device manager does not show an item and a model/brand . It’s a generic statement “ Device Failed Enumeration Error 43)”, under USB item . Also, the keyboard is a generic one, from brand “Multilaser”, a Brazilian importer of Chinese parts.